# using jQuery to toggle hidden text that's in a wp_query loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, foreach

Ok so i have 5 images that when selected shows a load of information on the picture underneath it. The images and text are being stored in a custom contact type. Now I have it working with the last image which is the first post in the custom content type. I'me new to writing my own jQuery so not sure if it needs some kind of for each loop?

Here the image class is given an ID so everyone is different

```
<a href="#" class="tutorlink-<?php the_id(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $TutorImageURL[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($att, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>" /></a>              
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="tutor-block">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/click.png" alt="tutors"/>
</div>

<div class="tutor-description">
<?php // The Loop
 while ( $tutors->have_posts() ) : $tutors->the_post(); ?>
```

Here the containing div class is also given its own id

```
<div class="tutor-description-inner-<?php the_id(); ?>">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

This script hides the text first.

```
<script>
var id = <?php echo $theID; ?>;
$('.tutor-description-inner-'+id+'').hide();
</script>
```

Here is the script I have written so far which toggles the text for the last image.

```
<script>                  
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.tutorlink-'+id+'').click(function() {
     $('.tutor-description-inner-'+id+'').toggle('slow');   
  return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd be better off using the id in an id attribute and then just apply the click event to the class "tutorlink"

```
<a href="#" class="tutorlink" id="<?php the_id(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $TutorImageURL[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($att, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>" /></a>
```

here's the description:

```
<div class="tutor-description-inner" id="tutor-description-inner-<?php the_id(); ?>">
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

and here's the click event

```
 <script>                  
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.tutorlink').click(function() {
         $('.tutor-description-inner').hide('fast', function() {
            $('#tutor-description-inner-'+this.id+'').toggle('slow');
         });   
      return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This worked a charm, thank you. Any idea how to hide the information when the next image is toggled?

Comment: you can add a class to the description divs and then run a hide on that class on the click event. then you can show the description you want in the "after" callback....(see edits above).

Comment: Thank you good sir. This worked but not in the function you placed it it. I took it out of the function and it worked fine. Cheers

Comment: ah sorry...I guess you need to specify the duration in the hide function if you are supplying the callback...this just guarantees that the toggle event doesn't fire until the hide event is completed. It's probably not a big deal as it will probably work all the time the way you have it. (see edited code)